# GraphQL Query error with Contentful and Netlify

Tags: graphql, contentful, structured-data, textnode

I'm not an expert coder but have this error in my Netlify Account where I am trying to update code and such and keep getting this error on my builds.

The error is :

```
GraphQLError: Field "jsonLdAnswer2" of type "contentfulTechnologyJsonLdAnswer2  TextNode" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "jsonLdAnswer2 { ..  . }"?
```

Where this started to happen is I was trying to put in more structured data attributes into place.

I tried going back to Github and looking at changes, and only action is I put in more structured data code.

```
 {
   '@type': 'Product',
    name: 'Okta Lifecycle Management',
    operatingSystem: "cloud software as a services",
    applicationCategory: "SecurityApplication",
    applicationSuite: "Okta Lifecycle management is a required product for Okta with Universal directory",
    softwareHelp: "deployment consulting and set up support",
    url: 'https://ironcovesolutions.com/technology/okta/',
    description: 'Okta Lifecycle Managment for speedy on and off deployment of users to cloud applicaitons',
    keywords: "okta, lcm, cloud, sign on, life, cycle, managment, users,onboard, quick",
    brand: {
      '@type': 'Brand',
      name: 'Okta',
    },
    offers: {
      '@type': 'Offer',
      url: 'https://ironcovesolutions.com/pricing/okta-product-price-sso-mfa-ud-amfa-sso/',
      priceCurrency: 'USD',
      price: '6.00',
      priceValidUntil: '2023-12-31',
      availability: 'https://schema.org/InStock',
      itemCondition: 'https://schema.org/NewCondition',
    },
  },
```

Comment: Hey, can you share more details, like your Content Model and the query you are using? You can also try out the query in the GraphQL Playground, fix the errors and then use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an Image at Contentful hanging up everything. I published 4-5 pages and one of the images in Contentful was not the right size for its area, and everything stopped. When I unpublished the page, one by one, it began to work again.